# In Eclipse How to send information entered into edit text field

Tags: android

Very new to coding but have accomplished quite a bit so far I am able to send an echo to the website from the application Ive been creating with this line of code

```
String url  = "http://beatswith.us/mtest.php?username=";
```

Anything after the = shows back in response... What I cant figure out is how to send whats entered into the edit text field to the url hereis the entire code so far

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;





import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Loginretrieve extends Activity {

EditText getInput;
TextView textOut;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.logpage);


getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);



String url  = "http://beatswith.us/mtest.php?username=";  

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response1;
try {

    response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    Object responseString = getResponseString(response1);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(responseString.toString());


} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}

public static String getResponseString(HttpResponse response)
    throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

String responseString = "";
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
            .getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        Log.d("beats.us.with", "Output");
    }
    in.close();
    responseString = sb.toString();

} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return responseString;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the httpclient tutorials? They discuss various ways to fill in and submit forms.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to send the data in the text field is this:

```
String url = "http://beatswith.us/mtest.php?username=" + URLEncoder.encode( textView.getText() );
```

If you want to send the form input as POST data, have a look at [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient).

Comment: Tried that continue to get error on textView. for some reason

Comment: My error comes on textView with 8 quick fixes when any of them are chosen the error goes to the .encode any help please